# Change hotkeys/shortcut keys for volume control

Tags: 11.10, sound, shortcut-keys, gconf, volume-control

I need to change the hotkeys for volume control, since I suffer from a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/808384), which disallows me to use the standard function hotkeys of my notebook.

Since I have updated I to Oneiric, I am not able to change the settings for the hotkeys. It is neither possible in system settings nor in gconf-editor.

Current buggy configuration:
Volume mute: Fn + F3
Volume down: Fn + F4
Volume up: Fn + F5

Desired configuration:
Volume mute: Ctrl + F3
Volume down: Ctrl + F4
Volume up: Ctrl + F5

If you need further information, I will be happy to provide it.

---

I tried to overwrite the standard settings by creating a new one in the “Custom shortcuts” category. Even this attempt is unsuccessful. Is there a possibility to access this menu as root?

Comment: May you please explain how it isn't possible? Do you mean you can't find the option, or that it is behaving weirdly? I'm asking because the option should exist in Keyboard›Shortcuts in System Settings. I just tested and on my end it does indeed allow me to set Ctrl+F3 to volume down.

Comment: I can find the option without a problem as indicated in the picture below. But when I click on Volume mute and then press Ctrl + F3, it just don't work. I have no idea, why this happens and what's going wrong, but I tried several times to change this option in the system setting, but did not succeed.

Answer (score 2):

Go to "System Settings" then "Keyboard" and the "Shortcuts" and select "Sound and Media".
There you can change the shortcuts to whatever suits you.

[image: Sound and Media]

Comment: See the comment above and also the question: I tried exactly this and it did not work. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry to have bothered you. All I had to do was to double click on it.

Comment: I don't think anyone is bothered -- this might help someone else at some point.