# How to disable sound/volume changes?

Tags: 12.04, sound

How can I force specific volume so it would always stay the same? I have a broken dashboard on a laptop which changes volume and randomly mutes

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can try to  remove keyboard shortcuts  corresponding to "volume up"  , "volume down" and "mute" in keyboard settings manager ,
 see 
[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67819/change-hotkeys-shortcut-keys-for-volume-control)